# $\lim a_n=\lim b_n=x$, show that the sequences $(g(a_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ and $(g(a_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ converge with the same limit.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**: Let $x\in{\mathbb{R}}$ and let $(a_n)_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ be sequences of rational numbers with $\lim a_n=\lim b_n=x$. Show that the sequences $(g(a_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ and $(g(b_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ converge with the same limit.

Given is the function $g:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq|x-y|$, $(x,y\in{\mathbb{Q}})$

**My attempt**: I have already proven that if $(a_n)\subset\mathbb{Q}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $(g(a_n))_{n\in{N}}$ is Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Given is

$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}b_n=x$

So $\forall \varepsilon>0 \;\exists N_1\in{\mathbb{N}}:n>N_1\implies d(a_n,x)<\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon$ and $\forall \varepsilon>0 \;\exists N_2\in{\mathbb{N}}:n>N_2\implies d(b_n,x)<\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon$.

Now let $N=\max{(N_1,N_2)}$. Then,

$\forall \varepsilon>0:n>N \implies$

$d(g(a_n),g(b_n))=|g(a_n)-g(b_n)|\leq |a_n-b_n|=d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a_n,x)+d(x,b_n)<\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon=\varepsilon$

I now wanted to show that $d(g(a_n),x)\leq d(g(a_n),g(b_n))$ but I'm not sure that's possible. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suppose that you mean $(g(a_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ and $(g(b_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ rather than $(g(a_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ and $(g(a_n))_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$. Then $\vert g(a_n)-g(b_n)\vert\leq\vert a_n-b_n\vert$  might help..